# Mongo DB connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I dont know why my code is not compiling, I have the following code.

```
mongoose.connect(db)
         .then( onFulfilled: () => console.log(`MongoDB connected.`))
         .catch( onRejected: err => console.log(err));
```

This is the error I get

```
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
/home/sambulo/Documents/linkshortenner/server.js:8
         .then( onFulfilled: () => console.log(`MongoDB connected.`))
                ^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.then( onFulfilled: () => console.log(`MongoDB connected.`))
```

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do here, it seems like you're declaring an object within the then clause where you actually want to have a function:

```
.then( () => console.log(`MongoDB connected.`) )
```

or:

```
.then( function onFulfilled () { console.log(`MongoDB connected.`) } )
```

EDIT: Same applies for `catch()`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `onFulfilled` and `onRejected`

Then make sure the `db` contains the database address.

Your final code should look like this,

```
mongoose.connect(db)
         .then(() => console.log(`MongoDB connected.`))
         .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

A Promise has a two methods `then()` and `catch()`,

```
Promise.then(() => {});
```

```
Promise.catch(() => {});
```

```
Promise
    .then(() => {})
    .catch(() => {});
```

In your code you need to remove `:` and update your code little bit...

```
mongoose.connect(db)
         .then((onFulfilled) => console.log(`MongoDB connected.`))
         .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```